# Returning a stream in a Spring repository using Redis, throws casting exception

Tags: java, spring, redis

My repository has this function:

```java
Stream < myClass> findAll();

and I'm calling it this way:

try(Stream< myClass> s = myClassRepository.findAll()){

    s.forEach(this::doNothing);

}
```

For some reason i get this exception:

`myClass cannot be cast to class java.util.stream.Stream`

Is the issue with my code or is this not supported by Redis?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you wrote

```
Stream <myClass> findAll();
```

on your own. This is not supported by default no. findAll() in repositories returns a list. It should look like this

```
List<MyClass> findAll();
```

the conversion to a stream can be done afterwards

```
myClassRepository().findAll().stream().forEach(this::doNothing)
```

or shortened

```
myClassRepository().findAll().forEach(this::doNothing)
```

Comment: Is there a function that can get a stream straight from redis?
maybe Stream<myClass> findBy...something

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with Redis. This is however not a Problem with Redis. The SpringBoot Repository is simply not returning the Class that you want. I am not certain but I dont think so. You could create a Proxy Bean which has the Repository and does the conversion manually. I however do not see the benefit.

Comment: I followed this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8
seems like it should work.. not sure why I get cast exception